# Include additional directories in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Where in Qt can I specify additional directories I want to be included to build my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Qt Creator IDE then I believe you must edit the .pro file directly. See the following link for details:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html

If you are using a different IDE, such as Visual Studio using the [add-in](http://doc.qt.io/vs-addin/), you can edit the include path as you would for non-Qt projects.

Answer (score 3):

By editing the corresponding `.pro` file accordingly.

One of the possible variables is `INCLUDEPATH`, and you can simply append via `+=` as e.g.

```
 INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/foo \
                /usr/local/include/bar \
                /opt/include/bing
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is there other way to do it? Like for example select those directories via dialog?

Comment: Whichever IDE you use (QtCreator ?) will *still* only modify the `.pro` file, so you may as well do it by hand.

Comment: I would rather not do it by hand, is there a way to do it via dialog?

Comment: There is no way to do it by dialog (and I don't see any advantage that should have?).

Comment: @Frank oh really? Why do you think Windows and other "Winows like" systems are so popular and DOS isn't?

Comment: smallB: This is about development. Everybody who is able to program C/C++ should also be able to edit a qmake .pro file. It's not magic, in this simple case, and I rather do it by hand than have some IDE manage otherwise cryptic and unreadable project files. That said, adding hardcoded, absolute included paths outside the .pro file isn't neither a good nor widespread practice anyway, as it would hardcode the specific setup on the developer's machine in the buildsystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you've already been told, adding paths to the INCLUDEPATH (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-common-projects.html) or, if you prefer, you can open your .pro file, and on the right where the content appears you can open the contextual menu. There you should see the item "Add Library...". A dialog appears where you can select which library to link to and which include paths to add to the .pro file. This is quite cross-platform and complete.

I've never used it, only saw it is there, maybe since version 2.1 or around that.

EDIT: I suggest anyway you learn how to write .pro files because you can do really interesting things.